# iOS: jQuery addClass after event only shows after another click

Tags: jquery, class, mobile, click, toggle

Currently I'm facing a really strange problem using a jQuery click event on my iOS device. I've made a map containing some div elements which visualize the rounded button and the tooltip, see below:

[image: Inactive state]

```
<figure class="map">
  <div data-city="amsterdam">
    <div class="tooltip">
        Amsterdam
        <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</figure>
```

The `div` with a `data-city` attribute is repeated for every city in the map. 
Trough CSS I've added the style and position using `relative` on the map and `absolute` on the div's.

Using jQuery I've added click events on every div. As you can see I'm also adding the data-city attribute to a hidden input (because it's being inserted in the database).

```
var city = $('div[data-city]');
city.on('click', function() {
    $('input[name="city"]').val( $(this).data('city') );

    city.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

After a div is clicked and the `active` class is added the div is displayed because the active class contains `display: block` instead of display: none. This looks like the following:
[image: Active state]

**Now the real problem**: 
This works perfectly fine on my laptop, but on my mobile device (iPhone 6 with iOS 9) the click isn't working smoothly. When a `div` is clicked, the hidden input is filled and the `active` class is added. Nevertheless the active state (turning light green and showing the tooltip) isn't showing. For some reason it only shows ***after I click another time*** somewhere inside the figure, but not on a div.

I've tried multiple things, like removing the CSS3 transition, disabled the hover event (on desktop the hover event is equal to the active state), tried another events (mousedown and tap) and triggerd a click with jQuery `.trigger()` after a timeout.. But unfortunately nothing seems to work

I couldn't find anything about such a problem, so hopefully somebody is familiar with this. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Try this: "city.on('click tap', function() {" -- Maybe it works

Comment: Thanks for your reply @LJa. Unfortunately this also doens't works. The same problems occur.